# why can't jQuery accurately query top style from inline css?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select based on a css attribute (in my case `top`).

HTML:

```
<i style="top:1px;">1px</i><br/>
```

JS:

```
$('i').each(function() {
    var top = $(this).css('top');
    console.log('top = '+top);
    if(top == '1px') j(this).css('border','1px solid green');
});
```

But this doesn't work. Top has the value 'auto'.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/qUjWq/

I'm guessing this has something to do with computed styles (?) but am not sure. What's up with this, and is there a way to distinguish tags based on style? (In my app I don't have control over the HTML that was written so changing it is not an option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beats me as to why, but you can just do this:

```
var top = $(this).get(0).style.top;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not jQuery, `auto` is correct. The `top` attribute is only used if the element is not positioned auto, ie: absolutely,

http://jsfiddle.net/qUjWq/2/

Otherwise you need to do what @Mike has shown.

Comment: see my response.  It doesn't have to be `absolute` positioning.  You just have to specify A `position`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `postion` attribute for the css for it to be something other then auto.  I've applied a `position:relative` [here (new jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/qUjWq/1/) and it's now working.

http://jsfiddle.net/qUjWq/1/

Answer (score -1):

I think there was just some typo in the original fiddle.
Check this out .
http://jsfiddle.net/eQVar/
I haven't changed anything.(just corrected the typo there was a j instead of $). So top can be used without the position. :)

Comment: in the jsFiddle you provided if you look at the Javascript console `top` is still equal to `auto`.  A position is required to reliably have `top` return a valid value.  Also the intended outcome that the OP was expecting (a border was to be applied) isn't happening.

Comment: @jared I rechecked the fiddle . It works fine in FF.:)
Checked it in Chrome and yes it doesnt work the way intended.

Comment: It also doesn't function under IE.  Between IE and Chrome you have just under 60% market share (last I looked) which is a rather large market to write js that doesn't function as intended.

Comment: @jared No Offences but you yourself didn't check the original code in FF.My Bad that I didn't check it in other browsers :)